# Android: Check if file exist and if not create new one

Tags: java, android, file

I tried to check if a file exist on my android and if not my program should create a new one.
But it always overwrites my existing file and is not checking if the files exist.
Here is the code for the file checking part:

```
File urltest = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/pwconfig/url.txt");
// check if file exists
if(urltest.exists());
else{       
// create an new file

File urlconfig = new File(myDir, "url.txt");
}
```

I really dont know why this is not working. It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: remove semicolon(;) for if condition and try again...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a "rogue" semicolon

```
if(urltest.exists());
```

Instead:

```
if(urltest.exists()){
    // do something
}
else{       
    // create an new file
    File urlconfig = new File(myDir, "url.txt");
}
```

If you don't want to do something specific, you could rework it as:

```
if(!urltest.exists()){      
    // create an new file
    File urlconfig = new File(myDir, "url.txt");
}
```

Be careful with declaring variables inside control blocks.  Remember that their scope is the control block itself.  You might want this:

```
File urlconfig;
if(!urltest.exists()){      
    // create an new file
    urlconfig = new File(myDir, "url.txt");
}
```

Comment: It's exactly the same.. `if();` is `if() { }`.

Comment: Yes, and therefore `new File()` is always called.  Have I missed something?  Using the braces just makes it more obvious (and maintainable), hence my suggestion to refactor to the 2nd form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();      
File dir = new File(sdDir,"/pwconfig/url.txt");

if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```